# Confused about armaFit function in fArma

Tags: r

I am trying to create a function to test out all combinations and find lowest AIC, kind of like auto.arima function. It seems however that I cannot use variables inside the armaFit function. This code works as expected:

```
library(quantmod)
library(fArma)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

getSymbols('SPY',from='1900-01-01')
spyRets=Return.calculate(Cl(SPY),method=c('log')) #log returns
spyArma=armaFit(~arma(1,1),data=spyRets)
```

However this code does not:

```
p=1
q=1
spyArma=armaFit(~arma(p,q),data=spyRets)
```

Why would this be the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because when you use a formula, it's assumed that all variables will be coming from the data.frame you pass via the `data=` parameter.

In this case, it would be better for you to build the formula dynamivally. One way to do this is to use `bquote()`.

```
p <- 1
q <- 1
f <- eval(bquote(~arma(.(p), .(q))))
spyArma <- armaFit(f,data=spyRets)
```